# hasClass on Bootstrap 4 carousel not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm building a basic narrowcasting system with a Bootstrap 4 carousel. Some slides contain images, others contain a Youtube video.

When a div contains a Youtube video, I want to autoplay it when the slide becomes active and stop it when the slide isn't active. But somehow the hasClass function does not recognize the 'active' class on my div with id="video-1".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" ); // added for testing
        if ($("#video-1").hasClass('active')) {
            console.log( "video loaded" ); // added for testing
            $("#ytplayer-1")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
        } else {
            $("#ytplayer-1")[0].src += "&autoplay=0";
        }          
    });
</script>
```

This is my html:

```
<div id="narrowcasting-carousel" class="carousel slide h-100" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="600000">
    <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
        <div class="carousel-item h-100 item-0" id="no-video" data-interval="10000">
             <img src="/images/image.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
        <div class="carousel-item h-100 item-1 active" id="video" data-interval="20000">
             <iframe id="ytplayer-1" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[CODE_HERE]?controls=0&amp;loop=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay">
    </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
        <div class="carousel-item h-100 item-2" id="no-video" data-interval="5000">
             <img src="/images/image.png" />
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

It does work when I use a onClick event or a keystroke event. But that's obviously not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" ); // added for testing
        if ($("iframe").parent().hasClass('active')) {
            console.log( "video loaded" ); // added for testing
            $("#ytplayer-1")[0].src += "&autoplay=1"; // You can refactor this line
        } else {
            $("#ytplayer-1")[0].src += "&autoplay=0";
        }          
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code is not working for me. hasClass still doesn't detect the active div